# GET /entity.svc failed in batch

Tags: odata, sapui5

I defined a service in `dataSources`

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "/backend/service/v1/entity.svc/",
        "type": "OData",
    }
}

"models": {
    "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "preload": true,
        "settings" : {
            "sizeLimit" : 500,
            "useBatch" : false,
            "refreshAfterChange": false,
            "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
            "defaultCountMode" : "None",
            "defaultUpdateMethod" : "Put"
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason I don't know, ui5 project will call `GET /backend/service/v1/entity.svc/` when initial load, which returns several `<collection>`.

But when I set UseBatch to true, the batched GET request will fail, with payload like this:

```
 --batch_67d5-9dc2-70e0
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET  HTTP/1.1
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
sap-cancel-on-close: true


--batch_67d5-9dc2-70e0-
```

As it seems like a GET nothing request, the batch request will certainly fail. Is there any UI5/oData expert can tell me what's the point of GET /entity.svc, how to fix this batch or how to skip this request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is cause by data binding in `sap.m.Table`

```
_bindView : function (sObjectPath) {
  var sAssignedPath = sObjectPath + "/assignedThings",

  this._oModel.read(sAssignedPath , {
    success : this._handleGetAssignedSuccess.bind(this, sAssignedPath),
    error : this._handleGetAssignedError.bind(this)
  });

  oTable.setModel(this._oModel);
}

_handleGetAssignedSuccess : function (sAssignedPath, oMsg) {
  var oTable = this.getView().byId("tableView").byId("assignTable"),
  oJSONModel = new JSONModel(oMsg.results);

  oAssignTable.setModel(oJSONModel);
},

//AssignTable.view.xml
<Table
  id="assignTable"
  inset="true"
  items="{
    path: '/'
  }"
>
```

`items="{path: '/'}"` is mean to use in JSON Model data binding, but it also triggered an oData GET '/' Request.